# Storing bytes more than what a heap has

Tags: c, string, malloc, heap-memory

why the code below succeeded although I just occupied 1 byte on heap using malloc():

```
char* sp=(char*)malloc(1);
strcpy(sp,"aaaaa");
```

`sp` has 1 byte heap size, and it can handle `aaaa` which is more the 1 byte! How it comes!

I am using MS VS 2010.

Comment: You are overwriting your Memory a common way for hacks and crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called undefined behavior.  Just because *your* compiler on *your* machine appears to have no problem with this does not mean that another compiler or another platform will behave identically.  (Hint: You're not seeing any ill effects because of the simplicity of this use case.  Anything more complicated and you'll wind up with major issues.)

Effectively, the assignment overflows your allocation.  What happens in that case is up to your compiler and your particular C/C++ runtime.  On some platforms this will result in a segfault or access violation (especially when using debugging aids like Electric Fence or Valgrind).

The *best-case* scenario with code like this is an immediate crash!  If the code does not crash then you likely corrupted another memory allocation, and your application will crash or corrupt data later -- a so-called "time bomb" bug.  Time bombs are *much* harder to debug, because the point at which the application crashes could be anywhere, and most likely nowhere near the bad code.

Answer (score 3):

This is called *undefined behavior*, and may *seem* to work at the moment. But most likely weird and seemingly unrelated things will happen later.

Answer (score 1):

Heap allocation is a co-operative exercise. By overwriting the end of your allocated space, you are not playing nicely, and bad things will happen.

It is your job to keep within the space you have been allocated. Nobody will stop you going over the end, or even writing on random bits of memory belonging to your program, but the results will be .... unpredictable. (Which is code for "bad").